# Codeigniter API: How to get data from mysql database based on users timezone in a Codeigniter API?

Tags: php, angular, api, codeigniter-3

- I want display GMT 0 todays data users timezone wise.
- I want data from mysql according multiple timezone. I have a GMT 0 data in a database. In my application there are multiple users globally. So i want calls data according to user timezone wise.
- I get data by GMT 0 timezone from database and then i convert that data into perticular users timezone. I want Arizona time zone mostly so it is GMT-7. When i get todays data user wise issue is that when GMT 0 and GMT-7 date is same result shows diffrent and if date is not same then result is correct
- I attached my Codeigniter API code of get chart data of todays calls. So if you have any solution Your thoughts are very welcome.

  ```
   <!-- Default timezone is UTC(GMT) 0 -->
   public function __construct()
   {
       date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
   }

   <!-- Controller API get todays calls by user current timezone -->
   public function getChartNumberOfCalls($company_uuid,$timezoneid){
       if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='OPTIONS'){
           return json_encode('OK');
       }
       $request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');

       $filterhrs = $this->api_model->convert_to_GMT($startdate,1,$timezoneid);

       $currdate = $this->api_model->display_to_GMT(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),1,$timezone1);
       $NumberOfCalls = $this->api_model->getChartNumberOfCalls($company_uuid,$currdate);

       $calls = array();
         $hrsarr = array();
         $keyhrsarr = array();
         foreach ($NumberOfCalls as $key => $value) {
           if($value['month']<10)
           $value['month'] ='0'.$value['month'];
           if($value['Hours']<10)
           $value['Hours'] ='0'.$value['Hours'];
           $convertdate = $value['year'].'-'.$value['month'].'-'.$value['day'].' '.$value['Hours'].':00:00';
           $date =  $this->api_model->display_to_GMT($convertdate,1,$timezone1);
           $calls[$key]['date'] = $date;
           $keyhrsarr[date('H',strtotime($date))]['keydate'] = date('H',strtotime($date));
           $keyhrsarr[date('H',strtotime($date))]['usage'] = $value['usage'];
           $calls[$key]['usage'] = $value['usage'];
           $calls[$key]['hrs'] = date('H',strtotime($date));
           $hrsarr[$key] = date('H',strtotime($date));
         }

         $arr = array();
         $iTimestamp = strtotime($filterhrs);
         $j = 0;
         $newdatepre='';
         for ($i = 0; $i <= 23; $i++) {
             $hrs = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $iTimestamp);  
             $hrs = $this->api_model->display_to_GMT($hrs,1,$timezone1);
             $hrs = date('H', strtotime($hrs));  
             if(in_array($hrs,$hrsarr)){
               $arr[] = (int)@$keyhrsarr[$hrs]['usage'];               
            }else{
               $arr[] = 0;   
             }
             $j++;
             $iTimestamp += 3600;
         }
        $arr1['data'] = $arr;
        $this->output
               ->set_content_type('application/json')
               ->set_output(json_encode($arr1['data']));
   }

   <!-- Model Code query to get calls data by current date  -->
   public function getChartNumberOfCalls($company_uuid,$currdate){
       if(date('Y-m-d')==date('Y-m-d',strtotime($currdate))){
           $start_date = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
           $end_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');           
       }else{
           $start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 day'));
           $end_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
       }

       $sql =$this->db->query("SELECT HOUR(start_stamp) AS Hours,day(start_stamp) AS day,month(start_stamp) AS month,year(start_stamp) AS year,COUNT(*) AS `usage` FROM calls WHERE (start_stamp BETWEEN '".$start_date."' AND '".$end_date."') and company_uuid='".$company_uuid."' GROUP BY HOUR(start_stamp), day( start_stamp ) ORDER BY start_stamp desc");

       return $sql->result_array();
     }



     <!-- Convert GMT 0 to current timezone -->
     function display_to_GMT($convertdate,$offset,$timezone_id){
           $this->db->select('gmtoffset');
           $this->db->from('timezone');
           $this->db->where('id',$timezone_id);
           $query = $this->db->get();
           $timezone_offset = $query->result();

           $USER_GMT = $timezone_offset['0']->gmtoffset;
           // echo $USER_GMT;exit;
           // $USER_GMT = '19800'; // 5:30 Indian Timezone
           $SERVER_GMT='0';
           $date_time_array = getdate(strtotime($convertdate));
           $hours = $date_time_array['hours'];
           $minutes = $date_time_array['minutes'];
           $seconds = $date_time_array['seconds'];
           $month = $date_time_array['mon'];
           $day = $date_time_array['mday'];
           $year = $date_time_array['year'];
           $timestamp = mktime($hours, $minutes, $seconds, $month, $day, $year);
           $timestamp = $timestamp+($USER_GMT-$SERVER_GMT);
           // echo $convertdate.'===='.$timestamp;exit;
           // $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
           if ($offset == 1) {
             $date = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp );
           } else {
             $date = date( "Y-m-d", $timestamp );
           }        
           return $date;
         }

        <!-- Convert current timezone to GMT 0  -->
         function convert_to_GMT($currDate, $fulldate = 1, $timezone_id = '') {
           $SERVER_GMT = '0';
           $this->db->select('gmtoffset');
           $this->db->from('timezone');
           $this->db->where('id',$timezone_id);
           $query = $this->db->get();
           $timezone_offset = $query->result();

           $USER_GMT = $timezone_offset ['0']->gmtoffset;

           $date_time_array = getdate ( strtotime ( $currDate ) );
           $hours = $date_time_array ['hours'];
           $minutes = $date_time_array ['minutes'];
           $seconds = $date_time_array ['seconds'];
           $month = $date_time_array ['mon'];
           $day = $date_time_array ['mday'];
           $year = $date_time_array ['year'];
           $timestamp1 = mktime ( $hours, $minutes, $seconds, $month, $day, $year );
           // echo '===='.$timestamp1.'===ok';exit;
           $timestamp = $timestamp1 - ($SERVER_GMT + $USER_GMT);

           if ($fulldate == 1) {
             $date = date ( "Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp );
           } else {
             $date = date ( "Y-m-d", $timestamp );
           }
           return $date;
         }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side programing language, it will only display the server-side time.

To get a user timezone you have to use client-side language i.e Jquery/Javascript.

```
var timezone_offset_minutes = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();

timezone_offset_minutes = timezone_offset_minutes == 0 ? 0 : -timezone_offset_minutes;

console.log(timezone_offset_minutes); // 300
```

This is just an example. In application, this will come from Javascript (via an AJAX or something)

```
$timezone_offset_minutes = 300;  // $_GET['timezone_offset_minutes']
            
// Convert minutes to seconds
$timezone_name = timezone_name_from_abbr("", $timezone_offset_minutes*60, false);
        
echo $timezone_name; //Asia/Karachi
```

Once you got the time zone, you can set `date_default_timezone_set($timezone_name);` also you can check it in the database, but for better practice try to save timezone by the user or allow them a change facility. It's good if you show them their current timezone.

I hope this will clear your query.